# want to merge PDF form which filled several times

Tags: c#, itext

I have one PDF form which is filled by supervisor(or a user).
I want to merge generated PDFs.
I have done simple merging but in it i have to first generate multiple files and then merge them.
Is there any way that when user fills multiple forms and then at the time of final submission or printing i get only a single merged of all filled PDFs.

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196124/merge-pdf-files

Comment: I have only one source file which is filled multiple times and then in the end i want to append all the filled files to be merged..

Comment: I understand your question to be that you have one form template that is used many times by many different people which can result in 'n' number of files in a folder. You wish to merge them. The link I posted is specific to itextsharp and merging. I've used this before and it works great.

Comment: Thank you.I appreciate your answer.
But it is not as i need.
I need that i fill the form 5 times one after another and when i press print or save it should print or save 5 filled forms merged.
I dont want 5 individual forms to be created.

Comment: Dude.. it doesn't create 5 files. It takes the 5 files you created either manually or in a loop or whatever.. and it merges them Did you even LOOK at the code?

Comment: I looked at it but i want 5 files to be created internally only and then merge them so that only 1 file is at output....

Comment: i want to create or buffer internally and then merge...
Thanx 4 ur great support

Comment: You can modify the code to use a List<byte[]> for the sourceFiles param. The PdfReader object has an overload that takes a byte[] ;)

Comment: @Hardrada : I couldn't get u fully.
Can u just give me some piece of code that can help me.
It would be great

Comment: see this param? string[] sourceFiles, change it to this List<byte[]> sourceFiles. Done..

Comment: See my answer post below

Answer (score 0):

Try out this Merge function to merge PDF files:

```
public static void Merge(string[] sourceFiles, string destinationFile)
{
    try
    {
        int f = 0;
        // we create a reader for a certain document
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFiles[f]);
        // we retrieve the total number of pages
        int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
        //Debug.WriteLine("There are " + n + " pages in the original file.");
        // step 1: creation of a document-object
        Document document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
        // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create));
        // step 3: we open the document
        document.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        PdfImportedPage page;
        int rotation;
        // step 4: we add content
        while (f < sourceFiles.Length)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < n)
            {
                i++;
                document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                document.NewPage();
                page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);
                if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                }
                //Debug.WriteLine("Processed page " + i);
            }
            f++;
            if (f < sourceFiles.Length)
            {
                reader = new PdfReader(sourceFiles[f]);
                // we retrieve the total number of pages
                n = reader.NumberOfPages;
                //Debug.WriteLine("There are " + n + " pages in the original file.");
            }
        }
        // step 5: we close the document
        document.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Reference: [Merge PDF Files using iTextSharp](http://www.khswsoft.be/Blog/tabid/81/EntryId/16/Merge-PDF-Files-using-iTextSharp.aspx)

Comment: I voted you down for a blatant rip of code from the original poster I linked to in my comment above. Add sourcing and links and I'll remove the down vote.

Comment: @Hardrada, I used this piece of code in one of my project from here http://www.khswsoft.be/Blog/tabid/81/EntryId/16/Merge-PDF-Files-using-iTextSharp.aspx and http://khsw.blogspot.com/2006/04/merge-pdf-files-using-itextsharp.html

Answer (score 0):

based off the merge code I sourced in my comments above.. 
I use this to write to the output stream of an http response. It returns a byte[], but you can use the original code and this to get the job done.

```
public static byte[] MergeFiles(List<byte[]> sourceFiles)
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            // Initialize pdf writer
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

            // Open document to write
            document.Open();
            PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;

            // Iterate through all pdf documents
            for (int fileCounter = 0; fileCounter < sourceFiles.Count; fileCounter++)
            {
                // Create pdf reader
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFiles[fileCounter]);
                int numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                // Iterate through all pages
                for (int currentPageIndex = 1; currentPageIndex <=
                                   numberOfPages; currentPageIndex++)
                {
                    // Determine page size for the current page
                    document.SetPageSize(
                       reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageIndex));

                    // Create page
                    document.NewPage();
                    PdfImportedPage importedPage =
                      writer.GetImportedPage(reader, currentPageIndex);


                    // Determine page orientation
                    int pageOrientation = reader.GetPageRotation(currentPageIndex);
                    if ((pageOrientation == 90) || (pageOrientation == 270))
                    {
                        content.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0,
                           reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageIndex).Height);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        content.AddTemplate(importedPage, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("There has an unexpected exception" +
                  " occured during the pdf merging process.", exception);
        }
        finally
        {
            document.Close();
        }
        return output.GetBuffer();
    }
```